# Dual monitor configuration finicky and not saving

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

So I just installed Ubuntu today for the very first time on a new SSD I got. I have two monitors and when I first booted up, they were flipped (it thinks my right monitor is on the left and vice versa).

I went into the display settings to try to orient them correctly, but whenever I drag them in place and hit apply, something strange happens. My mouse clicks on my left monitor affect the windows on my right monitor (and vice versa). After trying the same thing a couple times it ended up recognizing my clicks on the correct monitor, but once I applied/restarted, my configuration had reset back to the wrong orientation.

I'm a total noob with managing my own Linux system but have used the OS in the past so I'm not afraid of the terminal or anything. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution ended up being simple enough to make me feel stupid. I just had to update my graphic drivers and it sorted itself out!